# Deleting a ringtone programmatically in android

Tags: android, title, ringtone

I know inserting a ringtone programmatically, 
but I want to know about deleting a specific ringtone from the system ringtone list.
What I know, is the title of the ringtone.

I googled a lot about it, but unluckily, couldn't find any way to achieve exactly what I want.

Please, guide me the way to delete the ringtone using title of the ringtone.

Comment: @Rishabh: I just want to delete the ringtone, that I inserted first. I hope that can be done somehow.

Comment: So you can go the directory & search with name that you previously inserted & after that remove it.

Comment: @MoshErsan: Yes, even I want to do that, but I need some really helpful solutions for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try as to delete an ringtone from `MediaStore.Audio.Media`

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtone_path);  
int roweffected = getContentResolver().delete(uri,  
       MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtone_path + "\"",  
       null);

if(roweffected>0){
  //ringtone deleted
}
else{
  //ringtone not deleted
}
```

**EDIT :** 
you can also remove RINGTONE from list as :

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtone_path);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

int rowupdate = getContentResolver().update(uri,
       cv, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?",new String[] {ringtone_path});

if(rowupdate>0){
  //ringtone update
}
else{
  //ringtone not update
}
```

Comment: What path should I provide to getContentUriForPath(), I only have the music path of sdcard, from where I am getting it to set as ringtone, and other than that, I am having ringtone title. Thats all, what I do have.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm : exactly just pass sdcard file path

Comment: I did the same as you suggested, but it actually deleted the original file, which I don't want. I just want that to be removed from ringtone list.

Comment: @Prosper: yes, I checked it, it deleted the original fiie, which I don't want.

Comment: I just want to remove it from the system ringtone list. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm : you are not getting me i'm saying after deleting the original file check   system ringtone list and tell me ringtone is still there or not?

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm : see my edit answer i have included another way for removing from system default list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21464/discussion-between-narendra-droidworm-and--k)